# Java gl shader syntax error

Tags: java, syntax, glsl, shader

I have a syntax error in line 10.

```
ERROR: 0:10: 'void' : syntax error syntax error
```

here is the shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoordinates;

out vec2 pass_textureCoordinates;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix

void main(void) {

    gl_Position = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
    pass_textureCoordinates = textureCoordinates;

}
```

I searched around for a while and the syntax seems right

Comment: Try just `void main() {`.

Comment: I didi that already...
still an error

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the `void` itself, but there is missing a semicolon **before** `void`:

```
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix; // <--- add the missing ;
```

Note, in GLSL any declaration has to be finished by a semicolon (`;`).

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification; Chapter 10 Shading Language Grammar; page 167; *declaration* rule](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf)
or [GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6; Chapter 9 Shading Language Grammar; page 202; *declaration* rule](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf).